# Django-Extra-Views: Inlines child model gets author none. How do I set it the same as the parent?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have been spinning my wheels on this issue for a day or two.  I have django web application that has 3 models

users/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def full_name(self):
        return (self.user.get_full_name())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_or_update_user_extendeduser(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            ExtendedUser.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.extendeduser.save()
```

playground/models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Customer_Name
    Customer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    SFDC_Customer_Record_Number = models.IntegerField(default='')
    Zone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    Government = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    customerauthor = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=ExtendedUser)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('playground-home')

class Vue_Quote(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Quote_Name
    Quote_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    SFDC_Golden_Opp_ID = models.IntegerField()
    Vue_System_Count = models.IntegerField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=ExtendedUser,blank=True,null=True)
    Quote_Type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='')
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('quote-detail',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I am using the 3rd party application django-extra-views to create a single form which allows a user to create a customer and quote at the same time.  Views.py:

```
class QuoteInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Vue_Quote
    fields = ['Quote_Name','SFDC_Golden_Opp_ID','Vue_System_Count','Quote_Type',]
    factory_kwargs = {'extra':1}

class CreateQuoteInlinesView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Customer
    inlines = [QuoteInline]
    fields = ['Customer_Name','SFDC_Customer_Record_Number','Zone','Government']
    template_name= 'quote_and_customer.html'

    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        form.instance.customerauthor = ExtendedUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return super().forms_valid(form,inlines)
```

All of this is working great except for that I am not able to save the author for the Vue_Quote model...I always get "None":

[Image of Vue_Quote.author = None from my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7D7d.png)

I have tried a wide range of solutions but cannot seem to solve this and I am finding very little documentation on django-extra-views to support my finding a solution.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the `customer` field is being properly set in the **QuoteInLine**?- if so, you could possibly fetch it from that field by adding a `forms_valid` to **QuoteInLine** and doing `form.instance.author = form.instance.Customer.customerauthor` (similar to how your doing it with the **CreateQuoteInlinesView**) **I've never used this add-on so just throwing out an idea**

Comment: @nealium this is my code for QuoteInLine:
class QuoteInline(LoginRequiredMixin,InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Vue_Quote
    fields = ['Quote_Name','SFDC_Golden_Opp_ID','Vue_System_Count','Quote_Type',]
    factory_kwargs = {'extra':1}

So no, customer is not being set here.  Not sure where I would set it.

Comment: `def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        self. Object = form. Save(commit=False)
        self.object.customerauthor = ExtendedUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form. Save(commit=True)
        for formset in inlines:
            formset.save(commit=False)
            #print(ExtendedUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user))
            formset.author = ExtendedUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            print("here comes the author")
            print(formset.author)
            formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`

Comment: I tried the above...my print statements are giving me the right name output from my custom user model but still, its not saving to the database....

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I've looked at the source code and tried to figure it out.. It's really abstract and **a lot** of inheritance

This would be my best guess:

```py
   def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        user = ExtendedUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form.instance.customerauthor = user
        for i in inlines:
            i.instance.author = user
            i.save()
        return super().forms_valid(form,inlines)
```

Or if you wanted to also define the Customer field in this forms_valid you could do it after the super call

You could try something like this:

```py
   def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        user = ExtendedUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form.instance.customerauthor = user
        customerObj = super().forms_valid(form,inlines)
        for i in inlines:
            i.instance.author = user
            i.instance.Customer = customerObj
            i.save()
        return customerObj
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  Unfortunately your solution has a similar result as mine - when I print out the value I am assigning to Author I see the correct user name but the value doesn't actually save when I check the record in Django admin or print it out to HTML template.

Comment: @EitanAschner I forgot to call `i.save()` in the forms_valid loop, so give it one more shot.. Maybe that was the issue. Very dumb of me, sorry